# Conditional Statement in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, conditional-statements

In C#.Net, We would use Conditional Statement like this below:

```
string Place = TextBox1.Text == "" ? "School" : TextBox1.Text;
```

How to use Conditional Statement in JavaScript. I am assigning one value to the TextBox, If there is no value then I want to assign "1" to the TextBox.

Here I used like this,

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtPlace.ClientID %>').value   = obj[1];
```

If obj[1] == "" then I want to assign "1" to the TextBox. How to assign? It can be done easily by using If statement. But I want to know how to use Conditional Statement in JavaScript? Is there Conditional Statement in JavaScript? If so then how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Javascript does support the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#conditional_operator):

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtPlace.ClientID %>').value = obj[1] ? obj[1] : "1";
```

Alternatively, you can take advantage of its short-circuiting [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_Operators):

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtPlace.ClientID %>').value = obj[1] || "1";
```

Comment: @Hamidi: thank you for your answer. But I dont have idea about OR operator. Here if we use OR operator what value would be assigned to the TextBox.

Comment: @thevan, the two lines are equivalent.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes I tried. You are right. thank you so much Daniel.

Comment: @thevan, if `obj[1]` is the empty string, it will evaluate to `false` and the second operand will be evaluated and returned, so the value of the text box will be `"1"`. If `obj[1]` is a non-empty string, it will evaluate to `true`, so the second operand won't be evaluated and the value of the text box will be the string stored in `obj[1]`.

Comment: `obj[1] || "1"` means that if `obj[1]` is [truthy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) -- i.e. anything but `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN` -- the OR statement will stop and return `obj[1]`. Otherwise, it will continue on to `"1"` and return that. The term short-circuit is used because once part of `a || b || c || d` evaluates to a truthy value, it stops and equals that value.

Comment: @Hamidi: thank you so much. I am new to JavaScript and I am learning JavaScript now a days. Really I have learnt a new thing from you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is conditional statement in javascript, it works the same way:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtPlace.ClientID %>').value = obj[1] === "" ? "1" : obj[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional (or ternary) operator is the same in JavaScript:

```
condition ? true-value : false-value
```

So your code would look like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtPlace.ClientID %>').value = obj[1] === "" ? "1" : obj[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is and it behaves in the same way as in C#.

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtPlace.ClientID %>').value = obj[1]==""?"1":"something";
```